# Update all foreign key navigations in entity core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, entity-framework-core

I have a class User.
UserOne and UserTwo are users.
I need to transfer all of UserTwo's foreign key relationships to UserOne.

I could do this manually by doing:

```
userTwo.PostsCreatedByUser.ToList().ForEach(a => a.CreatedByUserId = userOne.Id);
userTwo.NotesCreatedByUser.ToList().ForEach(a => a.CreatedByUserId = userOne.Id);
context.SaveChanges();
```

But I was wondering if there was a way to do this **dynamically**?
With the above method, if I were to add a new table with a CreatedByUserId column, I would have to go back to this procedure and update it with the new collection.

Here is an outline of the example classes:

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        PostsCreatedByUser = new HashSet<Post>();
        NotesCreatedByUser = new HashSet<Note>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Posts> PostsCreatedByUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Notes> NotesCreatedByUser { get; set; }
}

public partial class Post
{
    public Post() { }

    public int CreatedByUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User CreatedByUser { get; set; }
}

public partial class Note
{
    public Note() { }

    public int CreatedByUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User CreatedByUser { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your only other choice seems to be reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection actions or if it satisfys your needs, you can create extension method for `User` entity like this;

```
public static class UserEntityExtensions
{
    public static void ConvertRelatedEntities(this User userTwo, User userOne)
    {
        userTwo.PostsCreatedByUser.ToList().ForEach(a => a.CreatedByUserId = userOne.Id);
        userTwo.NotesCreatedByUser.ToList().ForEach(a => a.CreatedByUserId = userOne.Id);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
userTwo.ConvertRelatedEntities(userOne);
```

If you need to add another collection which will be updated, you can put it to extension method. You can manage it more easily.

Comment: Does this really have any benefits? You still need to adjust code for new collections. Besides that, you outsource domain logic which I would rather keep within domain entity. This makes it easier to maintain strong encapsulation.

Comment: Yes, the developer should add the new collections if it needs. Also, "outsource domain logic" What exactly do you mean I couldn't understand ? By the way, I think, It should more easier to maintain convertion process. Because the developer haven't to change all code lines which perform convertion process. It is enough to just change ConvertRelatedEntities method.

Comment: In this exact case, putting domain logic in some extension class will not hurt, you are right. But you won't be able to access private or protected members. What if a protected timestamp should be updated inside the User Entity whenever the assignment is done? What if the entity needs to emit a domain event for each re-assigned collection? Assigning and event creation should be one atomic step. With an extension you either break this or need to pass around some event aggregation component.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Of course for different cases, the developer should handle them. I answered and suggested this answer according to the question and details that has been described by OP.

Comment: I don't think you did: *I would have to go back to this procedure and update it with the new collection*. OP still has to do that, the only difference is the location of "this procedure".

Comment: @Gert Arnold, Imagine that, the OP provides that codes 10 different places. If new collection has been added, he has to change 10 place. In this way, he has to change just one place.

Comment: That's not what OP says, then it wouldn't be "this procedure". They only want to make the update automatically include any collection that may be added later without changing any code of the update process. (Which I personally think is over-engineering).